# Linux Error: -bash syntax error near unexpected token 'KERN_INFO"

Tags: bash, linux-kernel, virtualbox

I just started my CSC 2260 class last week, we are using Virtual Box to work with Linux, and for this assignment we are learning about kernels. I got the hand of adding them, loading them, and unloading them. However, I am having an issue when it comes to trying to find the golden ratio using the code the professor gave. She asks us to get the value using printk(KERN_INFO "%lu\n", GOLDEN_RATIO_PRIME); But when I do, I get a bash syntax error about unexpected tokens. I am new to this sort of coding and was wondering if anyone knew what I was doing wrong.

Here is a picture of the output, if it helps. [image]

Comment: @SeanBright Thanks for the quick response. The teacher had us 'wget' an archive and then look through it to find a simple.c file and read it. after that, the idea was that we would unload the module and continue on from there. So maybe im just misunderstanding her and I need to reload the module, to use that simple.c file to do the golden ratio?

Comment: @Zethos The explanation is missing the crucial step of editing and compiling the module (i.e. `simple.c`). Was this not explained? It seems to me that prior C knowledge would be expected in a kernel programming course. Is that the case?

Comment: @SeanBright You'll have to forgive my general lack of info on the subject. I tried doing all of what you said and it gave me the error ''GOLDEN_RATIO_PRIME' undeclared (first use in this function)'

Comment: @uneven_mark The instructions she gave are a little hard to follow, im afraid. I did take one semester of C++, Its taking me time to see the similarities with bash and C++.

Comment: @Zethos You are not supposed to use bash for the code. You are supposed to open the simple.c file in an editor of your choice, add the line at the required place, save it, compile it (e.g. by calling `make` in bash in the folder if there is a Makefile), and then call `insmod [Name of the module file]` to load the resulting kernel module.

Comment: @Zethos `GOLDEN_RATIO_PRIME` is a macro defined in `linux/hash.h`. If this is what your teacher meant, you might need to include that header in `simple.c` as well. (Works the same way as in C++).

Comment: @uneven_mark You were right, the header wasn't present in the file.

Comment: @Zethos Then it might be a better idea to open a new question with the contents of the `simple.c` that you modified and compiled and to ask what the new error messages mean.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198396/discussion-between-zethos-and-uneven-mark).

Comment: Was this issue solved? I encountered the same issue and would like to hear about your solution. Thanks.